# CsvHelper dropping quotes

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I have huge .csv files which ones I wanna put into list exactly as they appear in .csv file

Eample .csv file row would be

`1141825007047,2019-02-18,02:55,"US","ATL","LAX","0","IAD","ORD","UA","UA236,UA208","UA2291,UA1155",2019-03-24 14:25,2019-03-24 22:20,2019-04-14 22:45,2019-04-15 08:54`

When I use CsvHelper and set parameters like:

```
csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true;
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
```

Then values like "UA236,UA208" gets splitted into two columns, which is incorrect in my case.

If I set params as:

```
 csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
 csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = false;
 csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
```

Then columns do get formatted correctly BUT it drops all the quoting. 
And it's dynamic thing regarding quotes, some columns will have it, some won't.

Desired output should be List of strings:

```
1141825007047
2019-02-18
02:55
"US"
"ATL"
"LAX"
"0"
"IAD"
"ORD"
"UA"
"UA236,UA208"
"UA2291,UA1155"
2019-03-24 14:25
2019-03-24 22:20
2019-04-14 22:45
2019-04-15 08:54
```

As requested, adding some code:

```
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myStream))
                {
                    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                    {
                        csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
                        csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = false;
                        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

                        while (csv.Read())
                        {
                            List<string> values = new List<string>();
                            string line = string.Empty;

                            for (int i = 0; csv.TryGetField<string>(i, out string value); i++)
                            {
                                values.Add(value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Yes, that's how CSVs normally work: quotes act as escaping, not part of the values. If you can't see how to configure CsvHelper to do what you want then you'll probably have to customise it.

Comment: It's probably recognizing quotes as being strings and just importing the strings.  Why do you explicitly need quotes inside your string value?  Where are you outputting the values that the quotes are needed?  It seems like you'd add quotes to the output where you need them.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to output the values?

Comment: @Nanhydrin  It simply goes to List<string> but I've added.

Comment: @David Quoting is important here, and while some values have quotes and some not, it's important in later steps

Comment: @Rup I this case, I don't know how to :) But any other library would be ok for me :)

Comment: @iJava that's just how CSV works. Either you *have* quoted text or not. It's probably simpler and safer to export the CSV file using either a different text qualifier or different field delimiter

Comment: okey..  seems I will need to go with something custom here

Answer (score 1):

You can get desired output by changing `Delimiter` to any character othere than `,` like `\n` with setting `IgnoreQuotes` to `true`

```
csv.Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true;
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "\\n";
```

Comment: I think the answer is outdated, IgnoreQuotes is not working in the last version. Now it should be achieved in this way: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1659
#### Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape,